# get_included_files() to another script

Tags: php

Is it possible use (a custom version of) `get_included_files()` to get the includes of another script? Like:

```
$ cat q.php
<?php
$foo = CUSTOM_get_included_files('/path/to/target.php');
```

Comment: if you need this, your probably doing something wrong.

Comment: `grep 'include(' *.php`? though if you want to be precise, you'd have to allow for include_once, require, and require_once.

Comment: why do you want to do that? if you know `target.php` you should also know which pages are included!

Comment: You could call `get_included_files()`, store the result, include your target script, and then call `get_included_files()` again. The difference would tell you which files were present after including the target file, but not before. I suspect this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/161671) or the result of an iffy design, though.

Comment: Thanks. This is not a design issue. I'm trying to get all included files by a PHP script **before** run a single line of code and without modify the script itself.

This is a prototype of my extension, not a legacy code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985094/how-can-i-list-included-files-in-php-script-from-rinit-function-php-extension/25001955#25001955

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. The list of included files is generated at runtime, and may depend on factors that can't be determined externally. Consider the following script, for instance:

```
<?php
...
if ($_GET["some_query_var"]) {
    include("lang/" . $_SESSION["language"] . ".php");
}
...
```

Depending on the input to this script, it may or may not include a file from the "lang" directory, and which file it includes will depend on the current state of the session. It's impossible to determine what it does without running it.

Answer (score 0):

By including another script, you are also including what it includes. Say I Have three scripts, A.php, B.php and C.php. B includes C. I want A to include B and C. All I'd have to do is have A include B, and then at run time A includes C as well due to B including it.

One strategy I use is to create a file called local_includes.php and fill it with every include I need, then every other file in the project just includes local_includes.php, and then they all have the necessary pre-requirements. In the same example as above, A, B, and C would all include this fourth file, local_includes.php, and local_includes.php would include A, B and C.